# How can I compile source code with javassist?

Tags: java, compilation, javassist

I have a `String` as:

```
public class Hesey {
    public void testAdd() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Is there a part of the API I could use for compiling this `String` to `Class` and load this 'Class'? Or do I have to use `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` for compiling the entire source?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [OpenHFT Java Runtime Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler).

It supports compiling Java source supplied on the fly as a string:

```
private final CachedCompiler cc = new CachedCompiler(null, null);

Class aClass = cc.loadFromJava(className, javaCode);
Object o = aClass.newInstance();  // instance of the object declared in 'javaCode'
```

where javaCode is a string representation of the Java source code.  Under the covers, I believe that it is using ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK, Javassist doesn't allow us to build a class from its text. The following is a piece of my code I used to build a class using that library:

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import javassist.CannotCompileException;
   import javassist.ClassPool;
   import javassist.CtClass;
   import javassist.CtField;
   import javassist.CtMethod;
   import javassist.NotFoundException;

   public class CtClassTemplate {

       public static volatile String                   CLASS_DEBUG_PATH = null;

       private final String                            name;
       private String                                  extendsClass;
       private final List<String>                      implementsInterfaces = new ArrayList<>();
       private final List<CtFieldTemplate>             fields = new ArrayList<>();
       private final List<CtMethodTemplate>            methods = new ArrayList<>();

       public CtClassTemplate(final String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public void setExtends(final String className) {
           this.extendsClass = className;
       }

       public void addImplements(final String ifcName) {
           implementsInterfaces.add(ifcName);
       }

       public CtFieldTemplate addField(final String code) {
           final CtFieldTemplate result = new CtFieldTemplate(code);
           fields.add(result);
           return result;
       }

       public CtMethodTemplate addMethod(final String code) {
           final CtMethodTemplate result = new CtMethodTemplate(code);
           methods.add(result);
           return result;
       }

       public <T extends Class> T createClass(final ClassPool pool) throws CannotCompileException {
           return createClass(pool, CtClassTemplate.class.getClassLoader());
       }

       public <T extends Class> T createClass(final ClassPool pool, final ClassLoader cl) throws CannotCompileException {
           try {

               final CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass(name);

               if (extendsClass != null && !extendsClass.isEmpty()) {
                   ctClass.setSuperclass(pool.get(extendsClass));
               }

               for (String ifc : implementsInterfaces) {
                   ctClass.addInterface(pool.get(ifc));
               }

               for (CtFieldTemplate field : fields) {
                   final CtField ctField = CtField.make(field.getCode(), ctClass);
                   ctClass.addField(ctField);
               }

               for (CtMethodTemplate method : methods) {
                   final CtMethod ctMethod = CtMethod.make(method.getCode(), ctClass);
                   ctClass.addMethod(ctMethod);
               }

               final String cdp = CLASS_DEBUG_PATH;

               if (cdp != null) {
                   ctClass.writeFile(cdp);
               }

               return (T) ctClass.toClass(cl, null);

           } catch (NotFoundException | IOException e) {
               throw new CannotCompileException(e);
           }      
       }

       public class CtMethodTemplate {
           private String code;

           private CtMethodTemplate(String code) {
               this.code = code;
           }    

           public String getCode() {
               return code;
           }

           public void setCode(String code) {
               this.code = code;
           }                        
       }

       public class CtFieldTemplate {
           private String code;

           private CtFieldTemplate(String code) {
               this.code = code;
           }    

           public String getCode() {
               return code;
           }

           public void setCode(String code) {
               this.code = code;
           }                        
       }

   }
   ```

You can use it like this:

```
    final ClassPool ctPool = new ClassPool(true);

    final CtClassTemplate aTmpl = new CtClassTemplate("foopackage.A");
    aTmpl.setExtends("foopackage.B");
    aTmpl.addImplements("foopackage.CIfc");
    aTmpl.addImplements("foopackage.onemorefoopackage.DIfc");
    aTmpl.addField("private int i;");
    aTmpl.addMethod("public int getI() { return i; }");
    aTmpl.addMethod("public void setI(int i) { this.i = $1; }");

    final Class aClass = aTmpl.createClass(ctPool);
```

OR in your case:

```
    final CtClassTemplate aTmpl = new CtClassTemplate("Hesey");
    aTmpl.addMethod("public void testAdd() { System.out.println(\"Hi\"); }");

    final Class aClass = aTmpl.createClass(ctPool);
```

Not really entire the text, unfortunately, but mostly it is :)

2. Using of ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() also looks OK (and OpenHFT Java Runtime Compiler is a good wrapper), but you will need to use JDK to run you application or to ship "tools.jar" at least. This may be not convinient.

Comment: However it seems the `import` part is hard to deal with, ClassPool supports `import` although, but if I make this tool for unknown code, I really have no idea what packages should I import :(

Comment: Absolutely. That's why javassist is a good tool when you need to modify existing bytecode or to build your own class (in that case I prefer to use fully qualified class names in the code). If you need a tool to build any java source file, then java.tools.JavaCompiler is the best one, I believe. It also provides good diagnostic and code analysis options.